# Why .edmx auto generation no longer in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, edmx

I just noticed new Entity Framework Core does not provide .edmx generation any more. But I was loving this because it helps me to focus on application logic, not always create class and do migration things to update database. Now my question is- Does Microsoft have any future plan to add .edmx on Entity Framework Core? Or its permanently gone from .Entity Framework Core? I searched over internet but didn’t found any good answer for that.

Comment: This was a design decision made by the Entity Framework team for EF7 and later: https://www.theregister.co.uk/2014/10/23/entity_framework_goes_codefirst_only_as_microsoft_shutters_yet_another_visual_modelling_tool/

Comment: You can use EF Core Power Tools for code generation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edmx is not there in Entity Framework Core. It only supports a code-first approach. It produces entity class files instead of an edmx file. You can use [dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet#dotnet-ef-dbcontext-scaffold), it scaffolds a DbContext and entity types for a database.

You can refer the document to start with the already existing database.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db

Answer (score 2):

I have not found any justification of this decision though I suppose this discussion can be found at least in some podcasts with EF team members interviews. In my opinion, this feature simply didn't deserve enough attention from developers and it didn't worth it to continue its support. Most people, as far as I'm concerned, moved towards code-first approach. You can concentrate on application logic even better with it, not creating any data objects in advance, but evolving your data structure together with business logic objects. That's what I can say based on my experience. Try it and maybe you will love it the same!

Answer (score -1):

If you are on heavy load complex database and developing application using this database continuously then there is no easier way than just press refresh button in .edmx file and get your new models ready to use. I think .edmx idea still deserves development for future. Lot of solution already made with it and continuing with .edmx